# confusion on caching data on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching

I am trying to cache data withdraw from the db so that the application does not need to query the data gain. Currently i am using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache` which appears to me is not really caching properly ( still slow sometimes).

```
If System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("data") Is Nothing Then
    ds = obj.getData()
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("data", ds, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1), TimeSpan.Zero)
Else
    ds = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("data")
End If
```

i have done some research and found out that there is another caching called HttpRuntime.Cache, which one should i use in this case?

Comment: It'll either be in the cache or it won't; I think your problem is that you're setting a value for absolute expiration - `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)` - and sliding expiration - `TimeSpan.Zero`. If you use absolute, you should set the sliding expiration value to Cache.NoSlidingExpiration.

Comment: i tried to use cache.noslidingexpiration, but it says cache no defined

Comment: Make sure you're importing the required namespace - System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration